# Login Check User Exists and is Set to Active

Tags: php, authentication

I have been trying to get the below code working for a few hours now. The idea is that it checks my database (b00543346) and the table "members" to see if a user exists (thus if their memberID is there. It then checks if a user is set to active.

At present not matter what username/password i enter and press login, this is displayed "Array ( [0] => Username Not Found. Have You Registered? )"

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT (`membersID`) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false; //check if user id exists
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT (`membersID`) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false; //check if user has activated account
}
?>

    <?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You Must Enter a Username AND Password';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Username Not Found. Have You Registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You Haven\'t Activated Your Account, Please Do So!';   
    }
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the returned value of  mysql_result(mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT (`membersID`) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0)?

Comment: the weird thing is, that even with sql error reporting enabled - it is not displaying an SQL error, just the array "username not found"

Comment: Do 
var_dump(mysql_result(mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT (membersID) FROM members WHERE username = '$username'"), 0));
in user_exists function;

Comment: NULL Array ( [0] => You Haven't Activated Your Account, Please Do So! )

Comment: So you receive null result, it is something with SQL query. How sanitize function modifies your username variable?

Comment: <?php
function sanitize($data) {
 return mysql_real_escape_string($data); 
}
?>

Comment: thats my sanitize function

Comment: i removed the sanitize function and it still displays the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** mysql functions in PHP do not like a space between the function name and the first open parenthesis. So ***count(`membersID`)*** will work, while ***count (`membersID`)*** will get you an error!

I'm curious what your sanitize() function is doing. If it at all modifies the username, it seems likely that your initial test data was input into the table manually and not run through the sanitize() function, then as the code sanitizes and perhaps modifies the data, it's not matching in the SQL.

You may also add some debug to your function to see a bit better what is going on. The current function is obfuscating some of what is happening. Try:

```
function user_exists($username) {
  print "DEBUG: username=[$username]\n";
  $query = "SELECT COUNT (`membersID`) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
  print "DEBUG: query=$query\n";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$result) {
    die('Could not execute query:' . mysql_error());
  }
  print "DEBUG Result Set Array\n";
  print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
  print "DEBUG just the result now\n";
  print mysql_result($result, 0);
  return mysql_result($result, 0) == 1;
```

}

Comment: yea i had manually input the data into my database, how would i go about correctly inputting it to get a valid output?

Comment: i tried removing the sanitize function all together and it still displays the same result

Comment: Write a helper script to insert them instead of entering them into the table by hand, and ensure that you also sanitize() the data prior to inserting it the same way you expect to sanitize in latter queries.

Presumably, long term, you will have a registration or admin page where new users are entered into the system. You would want to ensure you sanitize() there in the same way as well.

Comment: but what i dont get even with removing the whole sanitize function it is still got picking up the user from the database?

Comment: if i enter the query SELECT COUNT (`membersID`) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = 'admin'#1630 - FUNCTION b00543346.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual directly into mySQL within phpmyadmin i get the following error

Comment: SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = 'admin' use that instead and it displayed admin result

Comment: Ohhh!  mysql doesn't like the space!  you need to use count() instead of count () !!!

Comment: thank you SO SO much, 3 hours spent on that and now fixed .. over something so simple! THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too fond of the standard SQL functions of PHP anymore, so I can't judge that. But have you tried

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username'
```

Comment: tried that above and it still gives the result "Array ( [0] => Username Not Found. Have You Registered? )"

Comment: Try, what user1866998 suggested and see the result... Is it valid?